# Complex group-by MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a table with the following columns:

```
boxid - nouns - username

1 - w1,w2,w3 - user1
1 - w3,w2,w4 - user2
1 - w1,w8,w5 - user1
2 - w7,w2,w5 - user2
```

and at the present I have a query that allows me to extract the following:

```
SELECT boxid, group_concat(concat(username,":",nouns) SEPARATOR "|") as listn  
FROM table group by boxid;
```

that query gives me back the following:

```
box1 - user1:w1,w2,w3|user2:w3,w2,w4|user1:w1,w8,w5
```

However, I would like to get all nouns of the same user without repeating users (but repeating words of every user), something like the following result:

```
box1 - user1:w1,w2,w3,w1,w8,w5|user2:w3,w2,w4
```

Can someone show me if this can be done with mysql and how? I have no idea of this...

(I can do this with php, but I think getting the direct result in sql would be faster...)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'd be very cautious of putting too much (any) logic into your database layer. Makes your code more difficult to read (you're making assumptions about the format of your data), much more difficult to test and tightly coupling the implementation to your database. Have you done any tests to verify if is slower and indeed whether it will have an impact for your application. Grouping in SQL isn't as efficient as you might think...

Comment: I see. I will compare PHP processing and MySQL query execution times and post back which was the fastest one. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT boxid, group_concat(concat(username,":",nouns_list) SEPARATOR "|") as listn  
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT boxid, username, group_concat(nouns)  as nouns_list
        FROM table 
    GROUP BY boxid, username
) a
GROUP BY boxid
```